# Programmatically extract contents on an MSP file using C# Or any tool to view the contents without applying the patch (example: MSI unpacker)

Tags: c#, windows, msi-patch

I would like to view the content such as fileversion, Filename, registry settings for an MSP file without installing the patch. Just like ([MSI Unpacker Link](http://www.jsware.net/jsware/msicode.php5)) which provide me with this data.

Is there a tool that could serve this purpose for an MSP file?

Comment: Have you tried [Wix](http://wixtoolset.org/) dark?

Comment: I suppose Wix generates a 'diff.wixmst' which is used later for generating the patch (.msp) it would be nice to know before hand what files will be updated without extracting the files. I know Orca does that. Im looking to extract the contents of the .msp file and export this list into a file(via command line)

Comment: Wix dark can disassemble MSI. Have you tried it on MSP?

Comment: No, I haven't tried. Can you try that on a single MSP file and get the details, summary, file version etc., ?